# Prevent spark/surge when connecting power cable (charging input bulk capacitor)

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply

In cheap off-line AC-DC SMPS you will probably notice a huge spark when you connecting the PSU to mains. That usually won't cause problem because your mains is far more capable to handle that surge.

However I'm designing a **USB-powered** DC-DC SMPS, the host (computer) will certainly trip (or burn) if the input capacitor of DC-DC is too large.

The only thing came to mind is to make charge slow and discharge fast (for the capacitor to do its job).

[image]

However this reduce the capability for the capacitor to stabilize any fly-back transient (e.g. inductive load).

Is there a standard way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB specification has a maximum for the *immediate* capacitive load.
For USB 2.0 I believe this is 4.7uF.
Perhaps this is changed for Type C or PD, you can view the standards for free.
https://www.usb.org/

A way to fix that is with a soft-start switch. For example MIC94042.

Comment: Thanks, so it works by slowly ramping up Vgs of a power FET ? I need leaded package though because I'm going to hand solder. AP22804AW5-7 seems to be specially designed for usb-power.